# Freeze script on some seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, freeze

```
$(obj).each(function()
// 1) freeze
// 2) then do something
});
```

**How do I freeze the script on some seconds?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(obj).each(function()
   setTimeout(function(){
      //do stuff
   },2000);
});
```

Comment: That will schedule all stuff to run after two seconds, so the code won't run one thing at a time, it will just wait two seconds and then run everything. For that there is no point in having the `setTimeout` inside the loop, it's better to schedule the entire loop to run later.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want something like `sleep` ?  You use the function [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) to call a function after a certain amount of time.  So:

```
$(obj).each(function()
  setTimeout(someFunction, 1000);
});
```

to invoke `someFunction` after 1000ms, or as Andy mentioned you can just define an anonymous function to be called.

Comment: That will just wait for a second, then run all of the function calls back to back. For that there is no point in having the `setTimeout` inside the loop, it's better to schedule the entire loop to run later.

Comment: it's not clear what he wants, my impression was that he just wanted a single wait of `x` seconds, then do something...

Answer (score 2):

You don't freeze the script, that doesn't work well in an enviromment like a browser, you use a timeout to schedule code to start at a later time.

The trick with scheduling code in a loop is to schedule the code to run at differnt time in the future, e.g. the first code to run after 1000 ms., the second code to run after 2000 ms., and so on:

```
$(obj).each(function(i) {
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    // do something
  }, (i + 1) * 1000);
});
```

Comment: Guffa, please give some feedback on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480490/remove-delay-on-hide