# Remove delay on hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, delay

```
(function($)
{
 $.fn.blink = function(options)
 {
  var defaults = { delay:5000 };
  var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

  return this.each(function()
  {
   var obj = $(this).find("img");
   setInterval(function()
   {
    if($(obj).css("display") == "block")
    {
     $(obj).fadeOut('slow');
    }
    else
    {
     $(obj).fadeIn('slow');
    }
   }, options.delay);
  });
 }
}(jQuery))

$('.blink').blink();
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="blink">
    <img src="image.png" alt="some image" />
</a>
```

This script removes image with transition effect, and then shows it back. So here are two steps: 1) hide, 2) show.

**There is 5 seconds delay on each step, it should be only when image is visible.**

**How do I remove delay from the hide step?** There should not by any delay when image is unvisible.

**Code is available on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcWDy/)**

Its a circle script, once fadeIn/Out is done, it should be started again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the delay after `fadeOut`, just chain the calls instead of calling them on their own interval:

```
$(obj).fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
```

I made some simplifications to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/vcWDy/2/

Comment: wow! how come I didn't think of that!...I guess it's time for bed (2 AM)!! :)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/Sj5sX/

I'm all ears for the jQuery Gurus for notes and improvements..

**UPDATE 2**: or http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/tzdxX/

---

Sorry I got your question backward :)
use:

```
$(obj).hide();
```

instead of:

```
$(obj).fadeOut('slow');
```

If you want to show it directly

use:

```
$(obj).show();
```

instead of:

```
$(obj).fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: there is a dublicate of options.delay (4000), which one is useful?

Comment: I didn't understand your question? also note that I've updated both example to use whatever value u pass to them instead of setting it hard coded